# Java inline class calling method in parent class

Tags: java, oop, swing, mouselistener

I'm working on a little Swing application and am in need of some assistance. I have an inline class for a MouseListener and inside one of the methods I would like to call a method in the parent class, however, `this` is an instance of the MouseListener.

```
class ParentClass
{
    void ParentMethod()
    {
        //...
        swing_obj.addMouseListener(
            new MouseListener()
            {
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
                {
                    //Want to call this.methodX("str"), but
                    //this is the instance of MouseListener
                }
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){ }
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){ }
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){ }
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){ }
            }
        );
        //...
    }
    void methodX(String x)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Note: the proper term is "anonymous inner class".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though `this` is an instance of the anonymous type, you should still be able to call `methodX("str")` - just don't prefix it with `this`.

If you want to be explicit, I think there *is* some syntax which lets you do it - you can write

```
ParentClass.this.methodX("str");
```

but personally I wouldn't bother being explicit unless you really have to (e.g. to disambiguate the call from a method in `MouseListener`).

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to do anything but to remove `this` from the call.

If you still want to use `this` you have to have the prefix `ParentClass`. E.g. `ParentClass.this.methodX(...)`... But that's just ugly and should be used when needed (naming collisions etc).

Comment: @khachik: Personal taste? I don't use `this` before any of my other method calls within a class.

Comment: me too, and this is why `methodX` referring to the container class sometimes confuses me. Just personal taste, you're right

Answer (score 0):

As other have stated, simply remove `this.` and you should be able to call method in the outer class. In those rare cases when the outer class and the nested class have methodS with THE same name and parameter list you call it with `OuterClass.this.someMehtod(...);`.

For cleaner code when writing anonymous inner classes, I advice you to use adapters. For many of Swings interfaces, there's abstract adapters implementing them and you only override the methods of interest. In this case it would be `MouseAdapter`:

```
class ParentClass
{
    void ParentMethod()
    {
        swing_obj.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
            {
                someMethodX();
            }
        });
    }

    void methodX(String x)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```