# How to make JButton event modify JFrame (this)

Tags: java, swing, inner-classes

I'm trying to make a JButton click event modify the JFrame the button is on.  The problem is the class itself is the JFrame (extending from it), so I can't invoke 'this' from the inner class that handles the event.  I found a solution which works but I think it could lead to other problems, so I'm trying to find another way.  The code is as follows:

```
public class ClassX extends JFrame {

...

     this.setTitle("Title1");  //works fine

     jButton1 = new JButton();
     jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {    
          public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {

               //this.setTitle("Title1");  //calling 'this' won't work inside an inner class

               //Ugly Solution
               JButton btn = (JButton) e.getSource();     
               JFrame frme = (JFrame) btn.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent();
               frme.setTitle("Title2");
          }
     });

...

}
```

I'm trying to avoid the multiple getParent calls, but can't find another solution.  Any ideas?  Is there perhaps a way to pass 'this' or any other parameter to the action listener method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can :

```
ClassX.this.setTitle("Title1");
```

Will do the job (and [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239022/java-inline-class-calling-method-in-parent-class/4239039#4239039) agrees with me).

Answer (score 1):

```
ClassX.this.setTitle("Title2");
```

Comment: In any case mine is more correct, since Riduidel said "Title1", when you want "Title2"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having an inner ActionListener class why not implement the ActionListener interface ?

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;


    public class ClassX extends JFrame implements ActionListener
    {

    JButton jButton1;

    public ClassX()
    {
        jButton1 = new JButton();
        jButton.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(jButton);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
    this.setTitle("Button Clicked!")
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
            ClassX frame1 = new ClassX();
                frame1.setVisible(true);
            }
           } );
    }
}
```